# Is “Sith Witch” a title, or a general term for female Sith?

Tags: star-wars, sith, female-characters, witches

In the story of Star Wars there have been instances where the specific Sith female was considered a "Sith Witch." However there have also been instances where the Sith female was just a Sith.

Now my question is... is "Sith Witch" an actual title bestowed upon certain Sith females that have completed some achievement, or is "Sith Witch" a general term for all Sith females?

Also any other terms and info about the title would be most helpful.

Answer (score -1):

I believe that a Sith Witch is one who practices Sith Magic:

http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Sith_magic

> Males who achieved mastery were known as Sith sorcerers, mages, magicians, or wizards, while females who practiced Sith sorcery were referred to as Sith sorceresses or witches.

Comment: Is there canon source for this? The word "Witch" in that Wikia article is wholly unreferenced